# What can cause the network connection to degradate from 1 Gbps to 100 Mbps

Tags: file-transfer, gigabit-ethernet

I have a home network with a gigabit router, 2 PCs with Windows and a NAS from Synology. All are connected to the router via ethernet cable.

When i bought the NAS, i was able to transfer data with a speed of 80 MB/s, but recently it dropped to about 11 MB/s. When i started to investigate according to Synology FAQ, i discovered that my NAS detects only 100 Mbps connection.

[image]

Meanwhile both PCs still detect 1 Gbps

[image]

and i'm able to transfer data between the PCs with ~110 MB/s, so the problem can't be in the router, but rather somewhere between the router and the NAS.
What should i check? Can it be the cable, can it somehow degradate over time? Can it be a firmware issue? Any experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the cable with another?

Comment: No, i will have to buy it first.

Comment: Can you borrow a cable from one of the PC's to test?

Comment: It was the cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping the network cable with another, to see if the link speed changes back to 1Gbps.

Comment: It did. I have no idea what could happen to the old cable, because it was just laying inside a kindof drawer and nobody and nothing was touching it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a reboot fixed it.

I was getting 1 Gbps with a cable, but later in the day it was insisting on 100 Mbps. I tried disabling Auto-Negotiation and forcing 1 Gbps but that didn't work. Then I rebooted and it did.

So if you got 1 Gbps with the same cable before, and you know the cable is new or otherwise fine, try rebooting.